# Add a SKSpriteNode to the main scene from another class which is not a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

So I have my main view where I can do things such as this:

```
player = [Hero spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player.png"];
player.position = CGPointMake(512, 384);
[self addChild:player];
```

This is done in the `GameScene`, which is my main scene, its loaded in the view controller like so:

```
-(void) presentFirstScene
{   // create and present first scene
    GameScene* myScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
    [self.kkView presentScene:myScene];
}
```

Now If I have a different class called `A` (an instance of this class can be found in `GameScene`) how can I add SKSpriteNodes in `A` to the main `GameScene`.

What is easiest/most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks,

Lewis

Comment: Needs more context. What superclass does A inherit from? What does it do, what is it's purpose? Is it a child of GameScene? Does it have a way to access GameScene (ie via self.parent or weak reference)?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D A is a class that contains logic for flocking behaviour. It has an array of "boids" in the flock. I want to draw and update these in my GameScene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A is generating nodes without GameScene explicitly requesting them, then you could use the delegate pattern. Have A call a method on its delegate when it has a new node to add.

Answer (score 1):

You can create method in your class A which returns SKSpriteNodes, for example:

```
// in .m
-(SKSpriteNode*)getHero {
    SKSpriteNode *hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithImageNamed:@"player.png"];
    // Add more customisation here
    return hero;
}
```

And in your GameScene you can call it like that:

```
SKSpriteNode *hero = [a getHero];
hero.position = CGPointMake(512, 384);
[self addChild: hero];
```

Remember to add class declaration to .h file:

```
-(SKSpriteNode*)getHero;
```

Hope this what you are after.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking this. I'm going to create a "list" of nodes then return them.

Was just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it!

Comment: alternative is delegate? But I suppose the solution is not that straightforward as above